# applications being installed and mounted to /Volumes not to /Applications Mac OS X 10.7.3

Tags: operating-systems, xorg

New on Mac.

When I install dmg packages, they are being installed/mounted under /Volumes and not being installed to /Applications folder.

How to fix this. Detailed instructions please, as I am new to Mac, but comfortable in Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The dmg files are actually disk images, so opening them will mount them to /Volumes where all disks go. Installing software from there is very simple, but depends on what's inside.

In most cases, after mounting there will be .app file inside (and even a link to Applications). All you need to do is to copy the .app file* to /Applications. Yes, it is as simple as that.

In some cases there are .pkg or .mpkg files inside the mounted disk image. To install you need to double-click such files and an installation process will start; just follow the process.

See this: [Installing Applications in Mac OS X](http://guides.macrumors.com/Installing_Applications_in_Mac_OS_X)

After installing the application, you could eject the mounted disk as shown in the link above.

Something else to keep in mind, common mistake that I've seen new Mac users do -- if you need an application to appear in the [Dock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_%28Mac_OS_X%29), you should not move the .app file from the mounted image **directly** to the Dock. This would result in a disk image opening every time when you open the application. If you need an application to appear in the Dock, you need to move the .app file to /Applications (or some other place different than the Dock) first; and then from /Applications to the Dock.

*the .app file is not exactly a file, but a directory or application bundle. Because of that most applications could be installed everywhere, although some would break if not installed in /Applications. This said, it is a good idea to install them in the default location /Applications.